# How to "modernize" classic SharePoint pages on-premises?

Tags: migration, upgrade, modern-experience, modern-pages, 2019

We need to "modernize" SharePoint pages after migrating from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019. Which options do we have?

There is lots of documentation around modernization and respective tooling [here in the Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-classic-sites) but this seems to apply only to SharePoint Online. Which is a pity.

Which options do we have on-premises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only current method to modernize is to recreate the pages.

Comment: My question explicitly targets pages but I assume the same applies to whole sites (on-premises), right? I can also ask this as a new question if the answer is "it's complicated".

Comment: You're correct. As with any site, you cannot change the template from one to another -- this has always been true and continues to be true for classic -> modern. You'd need to use a content migration tool.